# BlockingConnection._flush_output when basic_consume

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

1. First I tried to delete the queue, close the channel and connection

   ```
   worker.channel.queue_delete(worker.queue_name)
   worker.channel.stop_consuming(consumer_tag=tag)
   worker.connection.close()
   worker.thread.stop()
   ```
2. And then I tried to create a new queue with same exchange, and try to publish message to the queue

   ```
   channel.exchange_declare(exchange=QUEUE_WORKER_EXCHANGE_NAME, exchange_type='direct', durable=True)

   # declare queue
   queue = channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=True)
   channel.queue_bind(exchange=QUEUE_WORKER_EXCHANGE_NAME, queue=queue_name, routing_key=queue_name)

   fn = BatchWorkerService.consumer_task_execution
   consumer_tag = channel.basic_consume(queue=queue.method.queue, on_message_callback=fn, auto_ack=False,
                                        exclusive=False)
   # listen to queue
   while channel._consumer_infos:
           channel.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=5)  # 1 second
   ```

Here is part for publishing message

```
    connection, channel = obtain_connection()

    message_dict = json.loads(message)

    # declare exchange
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=QUEUE_WORKER_EXCHANGE_NAME, exchange_type='direct', durable=True)

    # make message persistent
    message_properties = pika.BasicProperties(
        delivery_mode=2,
    )
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange=QUEUE_WORKER_EXCHANGE_NAME,
        routing_key=message_dict['batch_name'],
        body=message, properties=message_properties
    )

    connection.close()
```

3. Then i got this exception

> Exception ignored in: ...
>   at 0x7fd27618a7c8> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/qt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
>   line 509, in 
>       (not waiters or any(ready() for ready in waiters)))) SystemError: error return without exception set